# Error al guardar, termina la sesión

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema, al intentar guardar un formulario este termina la sesión por logout. No encuentro como corregir el problema.

Saludos y gracias.

Controller:

```
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App;
    use Auth;
    use Crypt;
    use Redirect;
    use Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


    class PerfilesController extends Controller
    {
      public function nuevo_perfil(){
        if(Auth::check()){
          $funcion = App\Funciones::orderby('nmb_funcion')->get();
          return view('perfiles/perfilnuevo', compact('funcion'));
        }
        else {
          return view('ingresar');
        }
      }

      public function guardarNuevo() {
          $perfil = App\Perfiles::insertPerfil();
          $identificador = Request::get('nmb_perfil');
          return Redirect::to('perfiles')->withErrors(array('message' => 'Perfil creado correctamente.', 'alertClass' => trans('acciones.class_exito')));
      }
    }
```

Modell:

```
        <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Request;

    class Perfiles extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'fb_perfil';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id_perfil';
        public $timestamps = false;

        public static function insertPerfil() {
          $perfil = new Perfiles();
          $perfil->nmb_perfil = trim(Request::get('nombre'));
          $perfil->estado_perfil_fk = "1";
          $perfil->fch_reg_perfil = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $perfil->save();

          return $perfil->id_perfil;
        }
    }
```

Al tratar de grabar en páginas con método POST, estos se van por logout antes de siquiera llegar al Controller, intenté al poner cun var_dump() en el controller, pero antes sale de la sesión

Comment: Muéstranos el código que estas implementando, sin código no podemos ayudarte amigo, [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  saludos.

Comment: Lo solucioné, no estaba cerrado el tag <form del logout, ahora no tengo problemas.